# C# Error invalid expression term ','

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The code :

```
  DataTable dt = Utility.GetProductByCatalogIds2("662, 663, 664, 665,666");

        List<object> listproduct1 = new List<object>();
        List<object> listproduct2 = new List<object>();
        List<object> listproduct3 = new List<object>();
        List<object> listproduct4 = new List<object>();
        List<object> listproduct5 = new List<object>();
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dt.Rows[i]["catalogID"].ToString() == "662" || dt.Rows[i]["parentId"].ToString() == "662")
                {
                    listproduct1.Add(new 

                    {
                        productID = dt.Rows[i]["productID"].ToString(),
                        ProductImg = dt.Rows[i]["ProductImg"].ToString(),
                        shortDesc = dt.Rows[i]["shortDesc"].ToString(),
                        ProductName = dt.Rows[i]["ProductName"].ToString(),
                        ProductPrice = dt.Rows[i]["ProductPrice"].ToString(),
                    });
```

` 
and for the other 4 lists are the same, i only change CatalogID.I got below error:

[image]

and 85 same Errors:

[image]

This is probably stupid question but I don't know what to do :(Can you please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: You may be using a .NET framework that does not have support for anonymous types... What framework is the server running?

Comment: also remove the last comma here `ProductPrice = dt.Rows[i]["ProductPrice"].ToString(),` it's telling you directly what the problem is

Comment: @MethodMan you don't need to remove that last comma, I forgot which language it comes from originally, but it's valid syntax. There's a story somewhere if you google for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

From the image it appears you are using .Net framework 2.0 with the version of c# compiler that doesn't support anonymous types and hence the error. By default C# compiler's version 2.0 will be used with .Net framework 2.0, and that doesn't support anonymous types.

Update the .Net framework version or specify an Application pool from .Net framework version 3.5 or higher *(if it is already installed)*.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using .NET framework version 2 or 3 which uses C# 2 compiler by default and does not support object initializers.

[Object initializers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) are introduced in C# 3.

Comment: It's not the framework that doesn't support anonymous types; it's the compiler. You can use a C# 3 compiler to target .NET 2 and still use anonymous types.